# how can I write fractional powers in python code like x^(2/3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I write `x^(2/3)` in python code?
I want to include `1/3` and `2/3` in my calculation but unable to do so. please help

Answer (score 4):

As you would do it with integer powers:

```
x ** (2 / 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here: 
Also, you can initialize `x`

```
x=3
x**(2/3)
```

Comment: it was not taking 2/3 but when i tried (2.0/3.0), it works